# Rvest: Looping through url's returns results for only element

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rvest

So here is my situation: I've had a lot of success looping through a series of URL's, usually created by scraping href(s) and appending them to a domain. This is the strategy I'm using here

```js
data = list()
for(i in 1:length(classes)){
  
  course <- read_html(classes[i])
  
  title <- course%>%
    html_node('h1')%>%
    html_text()
    
  description <- course%>%
    html_node('.block_content')%>%
    html_text()
  
  data[[length(data) + 1]] <- list(Title=title, Description=description)
}
```

classes is a bunch of strings looking like this (cutting off endings and beginning since they are links and I don't have the rep)

```
   [1] "ttp://catalog.pomona.edu/preview_course_nopop.php?catoid=" 
   [2] "ttp://catalog.pomona.edu/preview_course_nopop.php?catoid=" 
   [3] "ttp://catalog.pomona.edu/preview_course_nopop.php?catoid="
   [4] "ttp://catalog.pomona.edu/preview_course_nopop.php?catoid=" 
   [5] "ttp://catalog.pomona.edu/preview_course_nopop.php?catoid="
   ...
   [2340] "ttp://catalog.pomona.edu/preview_course_nopop.php?catoid"
```

The links work with no issue when tested individually; the loop will also run fine if I request a specific url instead of the whole index. However, if I run it for the entire length of classes, it runs for a long time and returns only a single result

```
> description
[1] "\n                  \n                      \t\t\t\t\t\tHELP\n\t\t\t\t\t\t2017-2018 Pomona College Catalog Print-Friendly Page [Add to Portfolio]                      \n                    THEA199IRPO - Theatre: Independent ResearchWhen Offered: Each semester.Instructor(s): StaffCredit: 0.5-1A substantial and significant piece of original research or creative product produced. Prerequisite course work required. Available for full or half-course credit.  Back to Top | Print-Friendly Page [Add to Portfolio]                  "
> title
[1] "THEA199IRPO - Theatre: Independent Research"
```

I'm honestly stumped considering a) I've been successful with this before and b) the links aren't broken. I get no error message either. Any help would be more than welcome !

Comment: You are just overwriting your variables in the loop. What is it you want?  Maybe a list of courses, titles and descriptions? You need to build the list,  not just store in the same variable.  Also,  it might be good for you to test on just the first few of your URLs,  not 2340 of them.

Comment: How would you recommend I go about this? Even we I replace [i] by a specific number, it runs for the same amount of time. I also edited the code to reflect the building of the list.